# Why can't programs run as administrator be a drag/drop target?

Tags: windows, uac

Ever since UAC was introduced in Windows, you haven't been able to use the elevated program as a drag/drop target - the "no entry" icon just appears when the mouse hovers over it.  I don't think there's a technical reason for this so what is the security justification?  It seems to me that you've already given permission for that app to do what it wants as admin like connect to the internet and access the file system, so why is being drag/drop target any more of a security risk at that point?

Comment: speculation: it's easy to accidentally bump the mouse and cause an inadvertent drag/drop.

Comment: If I understand your question, this is due to [UIPI (User Interface Privilege Isolation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Interface_Privilege_Isolation).